# How to avoid additional parenthesis level on each macro recursion in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, macros, lisp

I have this recursive macro `m1` which is called by macro `m1-do`. The purpose is to generate some function calls.

```
(defmacro m1 [fname x]
  (if (= (count x) 1)
    (let [a0 (first x)]
      `(~fname ~a0))
    (let [[a0 & arest] x]
      `((~fname ~a0) (m1 ~fname ~arest)))))

(defmacro m1-do [fname x]
  `(do (m1 ~fname ~x)))
```

This is what I want to achive as a result:

```
(m1-do f1 (45 98 122 143 215)) =>
(do (f1 45) (f1 98) (f1 122) (f1 143) (f1 215))
```

But instead I get an additional parenthesis level on each recursion. The first result already has too many of them:

```
user=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(m1-do f1 (45 98)))
(do ((f1 45) (f1 98)))
user=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(m1-do f1 (45 98 122)))
(do ((f1 45) ((f1 98) (f1 122))))
user=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(m1-do f1 (45 98 122 143)))
(do ((f1 45) ((f1 98) ((f1 122) (f1 143)))))
user=> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(m1-do f1 (45 98 122 143 215)))
(do ((f1 45) ((f1 98) ((f1 122) ((f1 143) (f1 215))))))
```

The problem seems that each call returns a list, which adds another pair of `()` and I also tried to develop some `flattening` function and use it within the macro with no success.

The numbers are only placeholders for the real content which is more complex.

Comment: I have seen this answer which uses `cons`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5261744/1431660 I could not make it work with `cons` because I run into quoting / unquoting issues.

Comment: I edited the example and removed one level of parenthesis in code line 4, but this does not help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a very simple non-recursive macro:

```
(defmacro m1-do [fname coll]
  `(do ~@(map (partial list fname) coll)))
```

Here is how you could do the same thing with `cons`:

```
(defmacro m1-do [fname coll]
  (cons 'do (map (partial list fname) coll)))
```

Both versions are exactly the same and produce desires output:

```
(macroexpand '(m1-do f1 (45 98 122 143 215)))
; => (do (f1 45) (f1 98) (f1 122) (f1 143) (f1 215))
```